# ViewPager2 resizing when keyboard appear

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to use the `ViewPager2` on my application, but I'm having some problems to implement it.

**The problem:**

> When I click on the `EditText`, the keyboard appears and the
> `ViewPager2` resizes, changing the `Height`

**What I want:**

> When I click on the `EditText`, the keyboard appears and move the
> view up and not resize the `ViewPager2`.

**How I can prevent the `ViewPage2` resizing and just move the view up when keyboard appears?**
There is any property to set?

**This is my manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**This is my `ViewPager2`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.BlankFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="403dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:text="Something Something Something Something"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<!--    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/view_pager"-->
<!--        android:visibility="gone"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="0dp"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"-->
<!--        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />-->

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager2"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**This is the fragment called inside the view pager**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:text="adasdasdasdasda"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb asdasdasdasdoahdjasd csdgv dfs bvdf b dsfb dsf bd fb dfb "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/section_label" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Wrong layout / What I want

[image: The problem layout]
[image: The layout that I want]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the Activity in your AndroidManifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

You can also test out `adjustResize` and `stateVisible` to see what works best in your circumstance.

Comment: Sorry dude, I forgot to post my manifest code... I already use the `StateVisible`

Comment: I edited, did you try `adjustPan` as well? Also, I normally put those in the `activity` element rather than the `application` element, but I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: Yes, I did... This "works", but it set the focus on the `EditText`, if I have a Button below I can't see it, then I want to move the view up. The `adjustPan` still resize the `ViewPager2`.

Comment: What if you use a ScrollView inside the ViewPager Fragment? Then it can scroll further.

Comment: It do not work too, I gave an example, but in the real app I have a structure somelike this: [Activity > NavGraph > Fragment > ViewPager2(Each page is a Fragment)]. There is some views on the parents too, like the TabBar, then it's because that I want move up the view.